# Getting same process details as task manager in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, memory

I have written a program to get memory details of the current running processes using `psutil` in Python 3. The problem is that the values I get are not the same as those from the Windows Task Manager. Specifically, how do I obtain the private working set size of a process in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

psutil calls [`GetProcessMemoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219), which doesn't break the working set down by private vs shared memory. To get this information you can use the Windows [performance counter API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083). Another way, which I demonstrate below, is to directly count the number of shared pages. [`QueryWorkingSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684946) returns an array of `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK` entries (one per page in the working set), for which you can tally the entries that have the `Shared` field set. You'll need a process handle, which you can get by calling either [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683179) or [`OpenProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320). To convert from pages to bytes, get the system page size by calling either [`GetPerformanceInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683210) or [`GetSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724381).

The downside to this approach is that you'll need `PROCESS_VM_READ` and `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` access to the process. If the current user is an elevated administrator, typically enabling `SeDebugPrivilege` gets around the access check, except not for 'protected' processes.

```python
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from collections import namedtuple

__all__ = ['query_working_set', 'working_set_size']

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
psapi = WinDLL('psapi', use_last_error=True)

PROCESS_VM_READ           = 0x0010
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400

ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 0x0005
ERROR_BAD_LENGTH    = 0x0018

ULONG_PTR = WPARAM
SIZE_T = c_size_t

class PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK(Union):
    class _FLAGS(Structure):
        _fields_ = (('Protection',  ULONG_PTR,  5),
                    ('ShareCount',  ULONG_PTR,  3),
                    ('Shared',      ULONG_PTR,  1),
                    ('Reserved',    ULONG_PTR,  3),
                    ('VirtualPage', ULONG_PTR, 20))
    _anonymous_ = '_flags',
    _fields_ = (('Flags', ULONG_PTR),
                ('_flags', _FLAGS))

class PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('NumberOfEntries',  ULONG_PTR),
                ('_WorkingSetInfo', PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK * 1))
    @property
    def WorkingSetInfo(self):
        array_t = PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK * self.NumberOfEntries
        offset = PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION._WorkingSetInfo.offset
        return array_t.from_buffer(self, offset)

PPSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION = POINTER(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION)

def errcheck_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())
    return args

psapi.QueryWorkingSet.errcheck = errcheck_bool
psapi.QueryWorkingSet.argtypes = (
    HANDLE,                         # _In_  hProcess
    PPSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION, # _Out_ pv
    DWORD)                          # _In_  cb

kernel32.GetCurrentProcess.restype = HANDLE

kernel32.OpenProcess.errcheck = errcheck_bool
kernel32.OpenProcess.restype = HANDLE
kernel32.OpenProcess.argtypes = (
    DWORD, # _In_ dwDesiredAccess
    BOOL,  # _In_ bInheritHandle
    DWORD) # _In_ dwProcessId

def query_working_set(pid=None):
    """Return the PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK array for the target process."""
    if pid is None:
        hprocess = kernel32.GetCurrentProcess()
    else:
        access = PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION
        hprocess = kernel32.OpenProcess(access, False, pid)
    info = PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION()
    base_size = sizeof(info)
    item_size = sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK)
    overshoot = 0
    while True:
        overshoot += 4096
        n = info.NumberOfEntries + overshoot
        resize(info, base_size + n * item_size)
        try:
            psapi.QueryWorkingSet(hprocess, byref(info), sizeof(info))
            break
        except OSError as e:
            if e.winerror != ERROR_BAD_LENGTH:
                raise
    return info.WorkingSetInfo

class PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = (('cb',                DWORD),
                ('CommitTotal',       SIZE_T),
                ('CommitLimit',       SIZE_T),
                ('CommitPeak',        SIZE_T),
                ('PhysicalTotal',     SIZE_T),
                ('PhysicalAvailable', SIZE_T),
                ('SystemCache',       SIZE_T),
                ('KernelTotal',       SIZE_T),
                ('KernelPaged',       SIZE_T),
                ('KernelNonpaged',    SIZE_T),
                ('PageSize',          SIZE_T),
                ('HandleCount',       DWORD),
                ('ProcessCount',      DWORD),
                ('ThreadCount',       DWORD))
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.cb = sizeof(self)

PPERFORMANCE_INFORMATION = POINTER(PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION)

psapi.GetPerformanceInfo.errcheck = errcheck_bool
psapi.GetPerformanceInfo.argtypes = (
    PPERFORMANCE_INFORMATION, # _Out_ pPerformanceInformation
    DWORD)                    # _In_  cb

WorkingSetSize = namedtuple('WorkingSetSize', 'total shared private')

def working_set_size(pid=None):
    """Return the total, shared, and private working set sizes
       for the target process.
    """
    wset = query_working_set(pid)
    pinfo = PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION()
    psapi.GetPerformanceInfo(byref(pinfo), sizeof(pinfo))
    pagesize = pinfo.PageSize        
    total = len(wset) * pagesize
    shared = sum(b.Shared for b in wset) * pagesize
    private = total - shared
    return WorkingSetSize(total, shared, private)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys    
    pid = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else None
    try:
        total, shared, private = working_set_size(pid)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.winerror == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED:
            sys.exit('Access Denied')
        raise
    width = len(str(total))
    print('Working Set: %*d' % (width, total))
    print('     Shared: %*d' % (width, shared))
    print('    Private: %*d' % (width, private))
```

For example:

```
C:\>tasklist /fi "imagename eq explorer.exe"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
explorer.exe                  2688 Console                    1     66,048 K

C:\>workingset.py 2688
Working Set: 67465216
     Shared: 59142144
    Private:  8323072
```

The following demonstrates getting denied access to a system process, even as an administrator. Usually enabling `SeDebugPrivilege` gets around this (note the privilege has to be present in the process token in order to enable it; you can't just add privileges to a token). Showing how to enable and disable privileges in an access token is beyond the scope of this answer, but below I demonstrate that it does work, at least for non-protected processes.

```
C:\>tasklist /fi "imagename eq winlogon.exe"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
winlogon.exe                   496 Console                    1      8,528 K

C:\>workingset.py 496
Access Denied

C:\>python
>>> from workingset import *
>>> from privilege import enable_privilege
>>> enable_privilege('SeDebugPrivilege')
>>> working_set_size(496)
WorkingSetSize(total=8732672, shared=8716288, private=16384)
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!