# python：how to get my windows process shared memory size？

Tags: python, windows, psutil

I want to get process shared memory size such as windows perfmon.exe shows. I used `psutil.Process().memory_full_info()`  and `Process(pid).memory_info()`，but I did not get shared memory.

How to get it? My OS is Windows 7, not Linux.

the following is my result:

```
pfullmem(
    rss=12562432L,
    vms=6787072L,
    num_page_faults=3173,
    peak_wset=12562432L,
    wset=12562432L, 
    peak_paged_pool=194528L, 
    paged_pool=193856L, 
    peak_nonpaged_pool=10552L, 
    nonpaged_pool=9560L, 
    pagefile=6787072L, 
    peak_pagefile=6787072L, 
    private=6787072L, 
    uss=7380992L
)
```

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228050/205580) for an example of how to get this information by using ctypes to call `QueryWorkingSet`.

Comment: thank you for your sharing @Martijn Pieters ,and my another question,how to get administrator privileges with in running this py files？

Comment: I tried to use 'runas /noprofile /user:Administrator "python .\xx.py"' , but it pops up another window

Comment: runas.exe calls `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, which necessarily creates the process with the flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` to ensure the console host process (conhost.exe) is created with the same access token as its client process. This allows the console to get an all-access handle for the client process and also allows it to read the user's console settings from `HKCU\Console`.

Comment: `CreateProcessWithLogonW` is implemented by calling the Secondary Logon service, which runs as SYSTEM and thus has the required `SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege` to call `CreateProcessAsUser`. This service is not designed to elevate, i.e. it doesn't execute consent.exe on the session's logon desktop to ask for the user's consent, and it doesn't use `SeTcbPrivilege` (trusted computer base) to get the unrestricted primary token of a UAC restricted administrator. You're using the normally disabled "Administrator" (RID 500) account to get around this, but that's a bad idea in general.