# Process and subprocesses information(memory)

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, windows-10, wmi

```
Get-Process -Id <pid>
```

returns only the information about that specific process, but what about all those which are invoked by this process.

Is there any way to know all the memory taken by a process and all processes which are created by that process?

Comment: how about checking the `psutil` module? (for python)

Comment: i am not familiar with it? is it useful?

Comment: super useful!!!

Comment: can you tell me the command which can be used for getting process memory and its subprocesses invoked by that process :)

Comment: don't know that by heart. Check the documentation.

Comment: Windows stores the PID of the parent process, but it doesn't actively maintain a process tree, so using psutil to determine the memory usage may return only a partial result.

Comment: If you add the root process to a Job object, you can track the peak memory usage of all processes in the tree (even orphaned processes) that haven't broken away from the job (assuming you allow breakaway). It's the `PeakJobMemoryUsed` in the `JobObjectExtendedLimitInformation`.

Comment: You can also maintain your own tree for all of the processes in the Job by associating it with a Completion Port, which will be notified whenever a process is added to the Job. Keep an array of handles for the processes, and query and total the memory usage of all processes that are running. Again, no orphaned processes will slip by, except for those that break away from the job on creation, if you allow that.

Comment: thanks you all of you :) right now i am trying to do it in psutil hope it will be working fine. i am testing it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell you'd define a recursive function to enumerate the child processes of a given process:

```bsh
function Get-ChildProcesses {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [int[]]$ProcessId
    )

    Process {
        $ProcessId | ForEach-Object {
            $_
            Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessID=$_" |
                Select-Object -Expand ProcessId |
                Get-ChildProcesses
        }
    }
}
```

then call `Get-Process` with those PIDs and expand the memory information:

```bsh
Get-Process -Id (Get-ChildProcesses 123) | Select-Object -Expand WorkingSet
```

Replace `WorkingSet` with `VirtualMemorySize` if you want the total allocated virtual memory of the processes rather than the physical memory they're using at the time.

---

In Python you'd use the module [`psutil`](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/), as Jean-François Fabre suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366903/process-and-subprocesses-informationmemory#comment77695008_45366903).

```bsh
import psutil

parent = psutil.Process(123)
for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
    print(child.memory_info().rss)
```

Replace `rss` with `vms` if you want the total allocated virtual memory of the processes rather than the physical memory they're using at the time.

Comment: the memory shown in taskmgr.exe of a process is not same of which rss is showing, can you tell me the reason?

Comment: The Task Manager shows the private bytes of the working set. `memory_info()` doesn't provide that information AFAICS, so you probably need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228050/1630171) to get it.